# Docker compose - container with command line instruments

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Sorry if the question turns out to be general one, any suggestions about updating the formulation would be appreciated!

So, I have java application which uses command line instruments for calculations. The calls are very rare. For example, it is possible that in 24 hours there will be no calls to it. The question, is what is the Docker way to containerize this?

There are a few possible solutions:

- put everything into one container
- separate tty container called by ssh
- develop http layer over instruments
- expose docker over systemd to start instruments container on demand
- expose docker over tcp to start instruments container on demand (https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#1-brief-introduction)

The questions is - am I missing something? Is there any other possible solutions? Are all the listed solutions viable? Is there a way to make it more clean using instruments like Swarm or Kubernetes?

Comment: Number 1) seems the wisest to me, you have no external depedencies, no network that can fail, no permission, everything you need in the same place. .. the only doubt would be how often do you update these command line tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker Way, in my experience, is your third option, to wrap the operation in an HTTP facade and leave it always running.

The HTTP path is well-supported by Docker (you can use other containers’ `--name` as hostnames for example) and it’s easy to test or simulate in other environments.  It also means that if you do need to make an update to one of these supporting tools you can just restart that other container; you don’t have to take your main application down to update it.

Docker doesn’t really work especially well with processes whose primary mode of interaction is command-line arguments, stdin, or stdout.  In particular for one container to launch another container *that container needs unrestricted root access over the host*, and you need to work with the Docker API and not just “launch a subprocess”.

If the external programs are fairly self-contained then COPYing them in the Dockerfile and calling them as ordinary subprocesses could work.  You mention Java; if you’re adding a whole JVM to an otherwise non-Java image for something you’re launching only occasionally that will add both bloat and complexity.